# Creating abbreviations list with manual entries

Tags: acronyms

How do I create list of abbreviations if I want to add them manually and not tag each abbreaviation in the file first (the file is already written)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple tabular-like environment?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}

\newcommand\nomenclature[2]{#1 & #2 \\}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{@{}p{1cm}@{}p{\dimexpr\textwidth-1cm\relax}@{}}
\nomenclature{$a$}{The number of angels per unit area}%
\nomenclature{$N$}{The number of angels per needle point}%
\nomenclature{$A$}{The area of the needle point}%
\nomenclature{$\sigma$}{The total mass of angels per unit area}%
\nomenclature{$m$}{The mass of one angel}
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to get a heading over this page in the same font size and same spacing as in the table of contents?