# Glossary like Two column supertabular problem

Tags: horizontal-alignment, two-column

First thing first, my code,

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[letterpaper, top=0.2in, bottom=0.15in, left=0.1in, right=0.1in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\twocolumn
%\tablehead{Header of first column & Header of second column \\}
\small
\begin{supertabular}{lll}
ABEX    ,   Abandonment Expenditure & EMV                   ,Expected Monetary Value\\
ACQ,            Annual Contract Quantity & EOR              ,Enhanced Oil Recovery\\
API,    Degrees API (American Petroleum Institute) & EUR            ,Estimated Ultimate Recovery\\
AAPG,   American Association of Petroleum &FEED             , Front End Engineering and Design\\
AVO,        Amplitude versus Offset & FPSO                  ,Floating Production, Storage and Offloading\\
A\$,            Australian Dollars &FSO                         ,Floating Storage and Offloading\\
B,          Billion (109) &Ft                               ,Foot/fee\\
Bbl,            Barrels &Fx                                 ,Foreign Exchange Rate\\
/Bbl,       per barrel &G                                       ,gram\\
BBbl,           Billion Barrels &g/cc                           ,grams per cubic centimetre\\
BHA,        Bottom Hole Assembly&Gal                        ,gallon\\
BHC,        Bottom Hole Compensated&gal/d                   ,gallons per day\\
Bscf or Bcf,    Billion standard cubic feet &G&A                    ,General and Administrative costs\\
Bscfd or Bcfd,  Billion standard cubic feet per day &GBP            ,Pounds Sterling\\
Bm$^3$,         Billion cubic metres &GDT                       ,Gas Down to\\
Bcpd,       Barrels of condensate per day&GIIP              ,Gas initially in place\\
BHP,        Bottom Hole Pressure &GJ                        ,Gigajoules (one billion Joules)\\
Blpd,       Barrels of liquid per day&GOR                   ,Gas Oil Ratio\\
Bpd,        Barrels per day&GTL                         ,Gas to Liquids\\
Boe,    Barrels of oil equivalent @ xxx mcf/Bbl&GWC         ,Gas water contact\\
Boepd,  Barrels of oil equivalent per day @ xxxmcf/Bbl&HDT      ,Hydrocarbons Down to\\
BOP,            Blow Out Preventer&HSE                      ,Health, Safety and Environment\\
Bopd,   Barrels oil per day&HSFO                            ,High Sulfur Fuel Oil\\
Bwpd    ,   Barrels of water per day&HUT                    ,Hydrocarbons up to\\
BS\&W,      Bottom sediment and water&H$_2$S                    ,Hydrogen Sulphide\\
BTU,            Bottom sediment and water&IOR               ,Improved Oil Recovery\\
Bwpd,       Barrels water per day&IPP                       ,Independent Power Producer\\
CBM,            Coal Bed Methane&IRR                        ,Internal Rate of Return\\
CO$_2$,         Carbon Dioxide&J                            ,Joule (Metric measurement of energy) I kilojoule =0.9478 BTU)\\
CAPEX,      Capital Expenditure&k                           ,Permeability\\
CCGT,       Combined Cycle Gas Turbine&KB                   ,Kelly Bushing\\
Cm,         centimetres&KJ                              ,Kilojoules (one Thousand Joules)\\
CMM,        Coal Mine Methane&Kl                            ,Kilolitres\\
CNG,            Compressed Natural Gas&Km               ,Kilometres\\
Cp, Centipoise (a measure of viscosity)&km$^2$              ,Square kilometres\\
CSG,            Coal Seam Gas&kPa                       ,Thousands of Pascals (measurement of pressure)\\
CT,         Corporation Tax&KW                          ,Kilowatt\\
DCQ,            Daily Contract Quantity&KWh                 ,Kilowatt hour\\
Deg C,      Degrees Celsius&LKG                         ,Lowest Known Gas\\
Deg F,      Degrees Fahrenheit&LKH                      ,Lowest Known Hydrocarbons\\
DHI,                Direct Hydrocarbon Indicator&LKO                ,Lowest Known Oil\\
DST,            Drill Stem Test&LNG                         ,Liquefied Natural Gas\\
DWT,            Dead-weight ton&LoF                     ,Life of Field\\
E\&A,           Exploration \& Appraisa&LPG                 ,Liquefied Petroleum Gas\\
E\&P,           Exploration and Production&LTI              ,Lost Time Injury\\
EBIT,           Earnings before Interest and Tax&LWD        ,Logging while drilling\\
EBITDA, Earnings before interest, tax, depreciation andamortisation&m           ,Metres\\
EI,         Entitlement Interest&M                          ,Thousand\\
EIA,    Environmental Impact Assessment&m$^3$                   ,Cubic metres\\
\end{supertabular}

\end{document}
```

What I want to have is pic below,
[image: What I want to have]

It's not a real glossary, so no need to introduce Glossary method here.
Tried multiple methods, no luck. Appreciated your instructions and help.

Comment: It's probably better to do this sort of thing using a simple list and `multicol` rather than as a table, because then it is easier to sort the input file.  Have a look at [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149708/simple-list-of-abbreviations-manually).

Comment: @Thruston Appreciated your link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach based on the linked answer above.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\newcommand{\abbrlabel}[1]{\makebox[1in][l]{\textbf{#1}\ }}
\newenvironment{abbreviations}{\begin{list}{}{\raggedright\renewcommand{\makelabel}{\abbrlabel}%
        \setlength{\labelwidth}{1in}\setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth+\labelsep}%
                                              \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}}}{\end{list}}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}[\centerline{\textbf{List of standard oil industry terms}}] \small
\begin{abbreviations}
\item[ABEX] Abandonment Expenditure                                       
\item[ACQ] Annual Contract Quantity                                      
\item[API] Degrees API (American Petroleum Institute)                    
\item[AAPG] American Association of Petroleum                             
\item[AVO] Amplitude versus Offset                                       
\item[A\$] Australian Dollars                                            
\item[B] Billion ($10^9$)                                                 
\item[Bbl] Barrels                                                       
\item[/Bbl] per barrel                                                    
\item[BBbl] Billion Barrels                                               
\item[BHA] Bottom Hole Assembly                                          
\item[BHC] Bottom Hole Compensated                                       
\item[Bscf or Bcf]    Billion standard cubic feet                                   
\item[Bscfd or Bcfd]  Billion standard cubic feet per day                           
\item[Bm$^3$] Billion cubic metres                                          
% etc                                         
\item[LWD] Logging while drilling                                        
\item[m] Metres                                                        
\item[M] Thousand                                                      
\item[m$^3$] Cubic metres                                                  
\end{abbreviations} 
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But you might also like to look at `siunitx` for all those units, and one of the chemistry packages for the chemical formulae.