# How to make a *Simple* acronym list, with no in-document usage or separate compiling?

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

I would like to print a **simple** list of acronyms at the beginning of my dissertation, something like:

---

## Acronyms

- **USA**  - United States of America
- **NBA** - National Basketball Association
- **PIN** - Personal Identification Number

---

I've tried using the `glossaries` package, the `acronym` package, and the `xindy`/`makeglossaries` programs, but they require steps like

- compiling a list of definitions into other files
- running `makeglossaries` or other scripts between `pdflatex` compilations
- using `\gls{}` within the document itself

In short, the `glossaries` package is a very complicated and capable tool, and it breaks everything when I try using it.

Does anybody know of a simple way to make an Acronym section at the beginning of a document that doesn't involve manually formatting?  Here is a pseduo-MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{simpleacronyms} %prospective solution
\input{acronyms}            %definition file

\begin{document} 
\frontmatter 
\tableofcontents 
\printacronyms              %put the acronym definitions here

%... dissertation here

\end{document}
```

Where `acronyms.tex` has content like

```
\acronym{USA}{United States of America}
\acronym{NBA}{National Basketball Association}
\acronym{PIN}{Personal Identification Number}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "doesn't involve manual formatting" but you could follow this answer:  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149708/simple-list-of-abbreviations-manually/149751#149751

Comment: why not just create a `\chapter*` containing the list using a `tabular` environment?

Comment: @barbarabeeton, That's basically what I did.  See the posted solution.

Comment: Packages `glossaries`, `acronym` and `acro` all can do this. »it breaks everything« is very unspecific. If you had posted a MWE showing *how* things break we might have been able to help… But it it looks like you found out how to use `acronym` and that is *doesn't* require additional compilation steps (contrary to your statement in the question) after all :)

Answer (score 4):

Found it!

---

***thesis.tex***

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{acronym}       %solution!
\begin{document}
\include{abstract}
\frontmatter 
\tableofcontents 
\include{acronyms}         %solution!

\mainmatter 
\include{Chapter1}
\include{Chapter2}
%...

\end{document}
```

---

***acronyms.tex***

```
\chapter*{Acronyms}
\begin{acronym}
 \acro{USA}{United States of America}
 \acro{NBA}{National Basketball Association}
 \acro{PIN}{Personal Identification Number}
\end{acronym}
```