# LaTeX manually insert List of Abbreviations in Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, acronyms

I wrote a document where some abbreviations are repeated several times. Therefore I wanted to introduce a list of abbreviations in the table of contents. I did not use any package to record the abbrevations, consequently I followed the approach reported in [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149708/simple-list-of-abbreviations-manually) to make my own one.

Since all my other lists in the table of content (i.e. List of Figures, List of Tables ecc.) have a specific layout for the title (it is like you call them using a \chapter*{List of ****} command), I wanted to introduce it also for my List of Abbreviations.Therefore, I wrote the code as below:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,titlepage]{memoir}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[font={footnotesize}]{caption}  %%%%%
\usepackage[font={footnotesize}]{subcaption} %%%%
\usepackage{changepage} %%%%
\usepackage{soul}
    \usepackage[linkcolor=black,colorlinks=true,citecolor=black,filecolor=black]{hyperref}
\newsavebox{\measurebox}
\newcommand{\abbrlabel}[1]{\makebox[3cm][l]{\textbf{#1}\ \dotfill}}
\newenvironment{abbreviations}{\begin{list}{}{\renewcommand{\makelabel}{\abbrlabel}}}{\end{list}}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter


%% TOC with the proper setup, do not change.
\cleartorecto
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\listoffigures
\newpage
\listoftables
\chapter*{List of Abbreviations}
\begin{abbreviations}
\item [A] Abbreviation
\end{abbreviations}
\mainmatter

\chapter{Chap}
Some text

\section{Sec}
Some text

\end{document}
```

My problem is that when I run this LaTeX file, I see the list of abbreviations title on the list of abbreviations page, but I do not see it in the "Contents" index.

How can I solve the problem and get it recorded in the "Contents" too?

Comment: Your document is only a fragment -- as well as `subfig` and `subcaption` don't work together. I doubt that you ever compiled this successfully!

Comment: Try adding `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Abbreviations}` after `\chapter*{List of Abbreviations}`

Comment: Please complete your given code to be compilable and reduce it as much as possible to contain only code resulting in your error.

Comment: I apologize I modified the code, now it should perform without errors

Comment: @TommasoSacco Remove the *

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is as easy as removing the `*`:

```
\chapter{List of Abbreviations}
```

Explanation: in the scope of `\frontmatter`, chapters are not numbered.

[image]