# adding a custom structure and giving a title to it

Tags: titles, acronyms

I have some big `acronyms` names and descriptions, and with [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/149751/208676) answer I could structure then well. However, now I want to put a big `title` in this structure, with same style as `List of Tables`, the text could be "List of abbreviations and acronyms".

I already searched it here, however I just saw explanations about `sections` and `chapters`. However, this list I created is something that stays out (and before) of `Contents` list.

Here is an example with only `acronyms` and each description:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\tocfill}{\cleaders\hbox{$\m@th \mkern\@dotsep mu . \mkern\@dotsep mu$}\hfill}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\abbrlabel}[1]{\makebox[5cm][l]{\textbf{#1}\ \tocfill}}
\newenvironment{abbreviations}{\begin{list}{}{\renewcommand{\makelabel}{\abbrlabel}%
        \setlength{\labelwidth}{5cm}\setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth+\labelsep}%
                                              \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}}}{\end{list}}
\begin{document}
\begin{abbreviations}
\item[US] United States
\item[EU] European Union
\item[Gvmt] Government. \lipsum[2]
\end{abbreviations} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: @cgnieder is there a way to configure alignment (to center) and size (bigger) of it?

Comment: @cgnieder alright, please add your suggestion as answer, it is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you wanted the same style as the list of figures and your MWE shows you're using the `article` class. In the `article` class `\listoffigues` does `\section*{\listfigurename}`. So `\section*{List of Abbreviations and Acronyms}` should do what you want:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\tocfill}{%
  \cleaders\hbox{$\m@th \mkern\@dotsep mu . \mkern\@dotsep mu$}\hfill
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\abbrlabel}[1]{\makebox[5cm][l]{\textbf{#1} \tocfill}}
\newenvironment{abbreviations}{%
  \begin{list}{}{%
    \renewcommand{\makelabel}{\abbrlabel}%
    \setlength{\labelwidth}{5cm}%
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth+\labelsep}%
    \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}%
  }%
}{\end{list}}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\section*{List of Abbreviations and Acronyms}
\begin{abbreviations}
  \item[US] United States
  \item[EU] European Union
  \item[Gvmt] Government. \lipsum[2]
\end{abbreviations} 

\end{document}
```