# good alignment of a text inside a chapter

Tags: alignment

In fact, I want to write a manual nomenclature inside a chapter that I named list of abbreviations, when I write that nomenclatures they are not aligned and there is a space in the beginning of the first nomenclature. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
 \usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
 \makenomenclature
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{unnumberedtotoc}
\usepackage[automark,
plainheadsepline,
headsepline,
plainfootsepline,
footsepline,
markcase=ignoreupper]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead*{\leftmark}
\cfoot*{\pagemark}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\scshape}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[a4paper,right=20mm,left=25mm,top=30mm, bottom=40mm,%
head=14.5pt,%<- new
]{geometry}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{20pt}
\titleformat{\paragraph}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addchap{Publications}
\addchap{Acknowledgement}
\printnomenclature
\nomenclature{FCB}{FC Barcelona}
\nomenclature{ASR}{AS Roma}
\nomenclature{FCS}{FC Sévilla}
\nomenclature{FCB}{FC Bayern}
\nomenclature{JFC}{Juventus FC}
\nomenclature{LFC}{Liverpool FC}
\nomenclature{MC}{Manchester City}
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\chapter{state of art}
\lipsum
\chapter{theory}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you want to write your nomenclature manually instead of using a package that is designed specifically for this purpose (`nomencl` or `glossaries`)? If you insist on a manual nomenclature, I would suggest using a `tabular` or even `longtable` environment to ensure a correct alignment of the abbreviations and their descriptions. Please also make your example a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). There are a lot of packages that are not needed to reproduce the issue you describe.

Comment: I still find problems, so for me the simplest way is by writing them manually. For the example the code is long because of the table of contents package. I don't want to use a table I think there is a way using \begin{array}  but it generates me some errors

Comment: `\begin{array}` is essentially a `\begin{tabular}` for the usage inside of a math-environment. You should use `tabular` or `longtable` if your nomenclature is longer than a single page. Alternatively you might be able to setup a nice looking nomenclature using `description` (maybe with the `enumitem` package to change the formatting a bit).

Comment: Also your nomenclature isn't unambiguous. You have the abbreviation FCB two times :)

Comment: Skillmon just an example lol

Comment: Related: [Simple list of abbreviations manually](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/149708/134144)  and [Creating abbreviations list with manual entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73074/134144)

Answer (score 2):

Although you insisted on not to use a `tabular`, here is a version of a manual nomenclature using a `tabular` environment:

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}

\chapter*{List of abbreviations}
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll}
FCB: &FC Barcelona\\
ASR: &AS Roma\\
FCS: &FC Sévilla \\
FCB: &FC Bayern \\
JFC: &Juventus FC\\
LFC: &Liverpool FC\\
MC: &Manchester City\\
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

The above presented manual approach is limited in some cases:

- Long descriptions that span more than one line would need the flexible width `X` column from the `tabularx` package.
- Long lists of abbreviations spanning more than one page would need the `longtable` package.
- Sorting of entries has to be done manually.

And here is an example on how to use the `nomencl` package to achieve an automatically alphabetically sortet nomenclature of the same enries. The `intoc` option includes the nomenclature in the table of contents.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\renewcommand{\nomname}{List of abbreviations}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\printnomenclature
\nomenclature{FCB}{FC Barcelona}
\nomenclature{ASR}{AS Roma}
\nomenclature{FCS}{FC Sévilla}
\nomenclature{FCB}{FC Bayern}
\nomenclature{JFC}{Juventus FC}
\nomenclature{LFC}{Liverpool FC}
\nomenclature{MC}{Manchester City}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps one should mention the other advantages of `nomencl` compared to a manual approach.

Comment: @leandriis the problem of nomenclature is the visibility on the table of contents

Comment: @twimo: `nomencl`'s option `[intoc]` includes the nomenclature in the table of contents.

Comment: Can you please edit your code including how I can use intoc

Comment: @twimo: Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Nothing happen the nomenclatures aren't visible, they are visible only in the table of contents I will write a code and compile to see by yourself

Comment: Did you compile your document using `latex` `makeindex` `latex` as described in 'Chapter 2: Usage'  of the `nomencl` documentation? `makeindex` is needed to sort the entries alphabetically.

Comment: I am working on TeXWorks I don't how to use makeindex

Comment: In the `typeset` menu button in TeXWorks you can choose from different compilers. Among them is `makeindex`.

Comment: Yes I have pdfLatex+Makeindex+Bibtex

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/421906/serious-problem-about-list-of-abbreviations-and-including-them-in-table-of-conte/421937#421937

Comment: Just noticed a drawback of `nomencl`. It doesn't clear the header.