# Serious problem about list of abbreviations and including them in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

When I displayed this code the list of abbreviations doesn't appear and also it doesn't appear in the table of contents:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
 \usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{unnumberedtotoc}
\usepackage[automark,
plainheadsepline,
headsepline,
plainfootsepline,
footsepline,
markcase=ignoreupper]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead*{\leftmark}
\cfoot*{\pagemark}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\scshape}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[a4paper,right=20mm,left=25mm,top=30mm, bottom=40mm,%
head=14.5pt,%<- new
]{geometry}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{20pt}
\titleformat{\paragraph}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addchap{Publications}
\addchap{Acknowledgement}
\printnomenclature
\nomenclature{FCB}{FC Barcelona}
\nomenclature{ASR}{AS Roma}
\nomenclature{FCS}{FC Sévilla}
\nomenclature{FCB}{FC Bayern}
\nomenclature{JFC}{Juventus FC}
\nomenclature{LFC}{Liverpool FC}
\nomenclature{MC}{Manchester City}
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\chapter{state of art}
\lipsum
\chapter{theory}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is the `unnumberedtotoc` package available somewhere?

Comment: yes https://github.com/johannesbottcher/unnumberedtotoc/

Comment: did you run makeindex?

Comment: The nomenclature shows up in your example after running `pdflatex->makeindex->pdflatex->pdflatex`.

Comment: If unnumberedtotoc is irrelevant to the question, omit it. If it is important, leave a link to it as I did in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following patches `nomencl` internals, so that a feature of `unnumberedtotoc` is available.

Important is, to run the commands as needed. See your own question from yesterday, where you can find it in the very first line (or the `nomencl` documentation).

[image: twimoNomencl]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{mwepage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\tracingpatches
\patchcmd{\thenomenclature}{%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\nomname}}
    {\addchaptertocentry{\nomname}\markboth{\MakeMarkcase{\nomname}}{}}{}{}
\makenomenclature
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[indentunnumbered]{unnumberedtotoc}%https://github.com/johannesbottcher/unnumberedtotoc/
\usepackage[automark,
plainheadsepline,
headsepline,
plainfootsepline,
footsepline,
markcase=ignoreupper]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead*{\leftmark}
\cfoot*{\pagemark}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\scshape}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[a4paper,right=20mm,left=25mm,top=30mm, bottom=40mm,%
head=14.5pt,%<- new
]{geometry}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{20pt}
\titleformat{\paragraph}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addchap{Publications}
\addchap{Acknowledgement}
\printnomenclature
\nomenclature{FCB}{FC Barcelona}
\nomenclature{ASR}{AS Roma}
\nomenclature{FCS}{FC Sévilla}
\nomenclature{FCB}{FC Bayern}
\nomenclature{JFC}{Juventus FC}
\nomenclature{LFC}{Liverpool FC}
\nomenclature{MC}{Manchester City}
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\chapter{state of art}
\lipsum
\chapter{theory}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

It is a bit pointless, imho, to ask questions on the same topic but for different ways. This seems very unstructured.

Comment: Does unnumberedtotoc  take care about hyperanchors?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer testing was fine so far, didn't test here.